# Why is C# so much faster at generating RSA keys than Python?

Tags: c#, python, .net, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I need to use basic RSA cryptography in my program so I use the [RSACryptoServiceProvider class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx) to do so.

I noticed it generates keys much faster than PyCrypto (Python) for example.

Here are some benchmarks I made:

**Execution times (.NET with RSACryptoServiceProvider)**

`Average generation time for 1024-bit key pair: 111,2 ms
Average generation time for 2048-bit key pair: 394,8 ms
Average generation time for 3072-bit key pair: 594 ms
Average generation time for 4096-bit key pair: 872,4 ms
Average generation time for 5120-bit key pair: 3351,4 ms
Average generation time for 6144-bit key pair: 4644,2 ms
Average generation time for 7168-bit key pair: 10052,8 ms
Average generation time for 8192-bit key pair: 16105,8 ms`

**Execution times (Python with PyCrypto)**

`Average generation time for 1024-bit key pair: 1.19569948638 s
Average generation time for 2048-bit key pair: 2.43145552844 s
Average generation time for 3072-bit key pair: 12.8203488201 s
Average generation time for 4096-bit key pair: 16.4437521276 s
Average generation time for 5120-bit key pair: 58.6469382781 s
Average generation time for 6144-bit key pair: 166.814121751 s
Average generation time for 7168-bit key pair: 132.13567301 s
Average generation time for 8192-bit key pair: 218.305013463 s`

**Ratio (Python/.NET) :**

`1024-bit key pair: 10,75
2048-bit key pair: 6,16
3072-bit key pair: 21,58
4096-bit key pair: 18,85
5120-bit key pair: 17,50
6144-bit key pair: 35,92
7168-bit key pair: 13,14
8192-bit key pair: 13,55`

As you can see, Python is about **17 times slower** than .NET.
Is Python really slow or does .NET use some kind of optimization to generate keys?

Tests were run on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit with an Intel Core i7 2600.

I used the following code to get these results:

#### `C#`

```
List<List<long>> executionTimes = new List<List<long>>();
int step = 1024;

for (int bits = 1024; bits <= 8192; bits += step) // 1024-bit to 8192-bit key pair
{
    executionTimes.Add(new List<long>());

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) // Run the test 10 times to compute an average
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generating " + bits + "-bit key pair...");

        Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(bits); // Doesn't actually generate the key pair
        rsa.ExportParameters(true); // Force generation of the key pair
        s.Stop();

        executionTimes[executionTimes.Count - 1].Add(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.WriteLine("Key pair generated. Time: " + s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms\r\n");
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i <= executionTimes.Count; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine("Average generation time for " + (i * step).ToString() + "-bit key pair: " + executionTimes[i - 1].Average().ToString() + " ms");


Console.ReadLine();
```

#### Python

```
import time
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

execution_times = list()
step = 1024

for bits in range(1024, 8192 + 1, step): # 1024-bit to 8192-bit key pair
        execution_times.append(list())

        for i in range(5):
                print("Generating " + str(bits) + "-bit key pair...")

                t = time.clock()
                RSA.generate(bits) # Generate key pair
                t = time.clock() - t

                execution_times[len(execution_times) - 1].append(t)

                print("Key pair generated. Time: " + str(t) + " s\r\n");


for i in range(1, len(execution_times) + 1, 1):
        print("Average generation time for " + str(i * step) + "-bit key pair: " + str(sum(execution_times[i - 1]) / len(execution_times[i - 1])) + " s")
```

Why is C# so much faster at generating keys than Python?

Comment: .NET uses a wrapper over the native implementation included with windows.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I guess the Python implementation is native code, too.

Comment: But even pure managed C# code should be much faster than what you give for python. My experience with optimized bigints in C vs. C# is that there is less than a factor 1.5 between equivalent code and a factor 3 if the native code uses 128 bit integers since those are not available in .net.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Python version: http://pastebin.com/0Zj1Jr3j
C# version: http://pastebin.com/jG9BiqK6

Comment: @GuiTeK The code should be in your question; not in a pastebin.

Comment: It gets worse when you run it from numerous threads. Try to call OpenSSL binary or wrap an OpenSSLn dll into you .net code to get best results.